# .ajaxComplete not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi i currently having a problem with firing .ajaxComplete function, whereby it should be working on a demo site. I'm refer to this function from here [http://www.bitrepository.com/a-simple-ajax-username-availability-checker.html](http://check%20username)

Here are my code :

```
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
<!--
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
Source: http://www.bitrepository.com/web-programming/ajax/username-checker.html 
*/

pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
pic1.src = "loader.gif";

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#userID").change(function() { 

var usr = $("#userID").val();

if(usr.length >= 4)
{
$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "check.php",  
    data: "userID="+ usr,  
    success: function(msg){  
   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

    if(msg == "OK")
    { 

        $("#userID").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
        $("#userID").addClass("object_ok");
        $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $("#userID").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
        $("#userID").addClass("object_error");
        $(this).html(msg);
    }  

   });

 } 

  }); 

}
else
    {
    $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
    $("#userID").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
    $("#userID").addClass("object_error");
    }

});

});

//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

I had try to alert the msg , the check.php able to return back the msg value, but it stop on the .ajaxComplete() there where it does not trigger the function after the .ajaxComplete(). Please guide me through this. Thanks

Comment: see the doc - http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ -`As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document.`

Comment: @ArunPJohny mean that? sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [document](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached
>   to document.

So

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
});
```

---

But in your code, there is no need to use ajaxComplete, the success callback will be called only when the ajax call is finished, so you can just check the value of `msg` directly in it.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",
            data: "userID=" + usr,
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg == "OK") {
                    $("#userID").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                    $("#userID").addClass("object_ok");
                    $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
                } else {
                    $("#userID").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                    $("#userID").addClass("object_error");
                    $(this).html(msg);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i had try but still not working...it still show "Checking availability" instead of "OKAY"

Comment: I had try with the code u suggest , but i'm not sure why it still showing the "Checking Availability" word